# Monitoring suspicious processes on macOS without Activity Monitor?

Tags: macos, process, malware

I've recently noticed my mac overheating and its fans ramping up after being left idle for a few minutes. What really makes me suspicious of it is that when I launch Activity Monitor to see what process is responsible for this, it immediately stops working so hard and starts to cool off, which makes me think this process halts when Activity Monitor is launched just like a mining malware would.

How can I inspect my running processes without launching Activity Monitor, and what do you suggest I do in order to make sure no malware is running in the background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could inspect running process by using htop or top, from within a a terminal (app).

https://feverload.embrasium.com/install-htop-macos/

However, if said malware detects activity monitor, it may look for top/htop too, or possibly other utilities.

you might also consider looking at spyware/malware detection / removal tools for Mac... Currently, I am not using any such tools on my M1 mac - so i don't have any specific recommendation.